# Mathematica can't evaluate the function at the point where it is smooth

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, syntax, singularity

Suppose the function

```
SingleCrossSection[Ss_, s2_, m_, m2_, mp_] = 
  -(1/(288 π^3 s2^3 Ss^4 (mp^2 - Ss)^2)) 
     ((m^2 - s2) (1/((m + m2)^2 - (mp - Sqrt[
           Ss])^2) (s2 - (mp - Sqrt[
            Ss])^2) Sqrt[-2 mp^2 ((m + m2)^2 + Ss) + ((m + m2)^2 - 
           Ss)^2 + 
         mp^4] (m^4 (-6 mp^8 + 3 mp^6 (s2 + 24 Ss) + 
             mp^4 (3 s2^2 - 27 s2 Ss - 172 Ss^2) + 
             mp^2 Ss (-30 s2^2 - 19 s2 Ss + 152 Ss^2) + 
             Ss^2 (35 s2^2 + 35 s2 Ss - 46 Ss^2)) + 
          m^2 s2 (3 mp^8 - 6 mp^6 (s2 + 12 Ss) + 
             mp^4 (3 s2^2 + 18 s2 Ss + 110 Ss^2) - 
             2 mp^2 Ss (15 s2^2 + 17 s2 Ss + 8 Ss^2) + 
             Ss^2 (11 s2^2 + 38 s2 Ss - 25 Ss^2)) - 
          s2^2 (-3 mp^8 - 3 mp^6 (s2 - 24 Ss) + 
             mp^4 (6 s2^2 + 63 s2 Ss - 134 Ss^2) + 
             mp^2 Ss (-60 s2^2 + 19 s2 Ss + 64 Ss^2) + 
             Ss^2 (46 s2^2 - 71 s2 Ss + Ss^2))) + 
       12 Ss^2 (m^4 (2 mp^6 - 3 mp^4 (s2 + 2 Ss) + 6 mp^2 Ss^2 + 
             s2^3 + 3 s2 Ss^2 - 2 Ss^3) + 
          m^2 s2 (2 mp^6 + 3 mp^4 (s2 - 2 Ss) - 
             6 mp^2 (s2^2 + s2 Ss - Ss^2) + s2^3 + 3 s2 Ss^2 - 
             2 Ss^3) + 
          s2^2 (-mp^6 + 3 mp^4 (s2 + Ss) - 3 mp^2 Ss^2 - 2 s2^3 + 
             6 s2^2 Ss - 3 s2 Ss^2 + Ss^3)) Log[-(
          s2/(-2 mp^2 + 4 mp Sqrt[Ss] + s2 - 2 Ss))]) - 
    12 Ss^2 Log[
      m2^2/(-m^2 - 2 m m2 + 
       s2)] (-3 s2^3 (mp^2 - Ss)^2 (m^2 + mp^2 - Ss) Log[-(
          s2/(-2 mp^2 + 4 mp Sqrt[Ss] + s2 - 2 Ss))] - 
       1/((m + m2)^2 - (mp - Sqrt[Ss])^2) (m^2 - 
           s2) (s2 - (mp - Sqrt[
             Ss])^2) Sqrt[-2 mp^2 ((m + m2)^2 + Ss) + ((m + m2)^2 - 
            Ss)^2 + 
          mp^4] (m^4 (-2 mp^4 + mp^2 (s2 + 4 Ss) + s2^2 + s2 Ss - 
              2 Ss^2) + 
           m^2 s2 (-2 mp^4 + mp^2 (4 Ss - 5 s2) + s2^2 + s2 Ss - 
              2 Ss^2) + 
           s2^2 (mp^4 - 2 mp^2 (s2 + Ss) - 2 s2^2 + 4 s2 Ss + 
              Ss^2))));
```

defined on

```
{s2, (m+m2)^2, (Sqrt[Ss]-mp)^2}, Ss > (mp+m2+m)^2, m \geqslant 0, m2>0, mp\geqslant 0
```

It is real smooth function in $m,mp$, and they both can be set to zero, whereas $m2$ can't be set to zero because of logarithmic singularity.

I'm evaluating the $s2$ integral:

```
CrossSectionIntegral[Ss_, s2_, m_, m2_, mp_] = 
  Simplify[Integrate[SingleCrossSection[Ss, s2, m, m2, mp], 
    s2, Assumptions -> Ss > 0 && Sqrt[Ss] > mp + m2 + m]];
CrossSection[Ss_, m_, m2_, mp_] = 
 Collect[CrossSectionIntegral[Ss, (Sqrt[Ss]-mp)^2, m, m2, mp] - 
   CrossSectionIntegral[Ss, (m+m2)^2, m, m2, mp], m] ;
```

Now I'm trying to evaluate the function `CrossSection[Ss, 0, m2, 0]` at zero $m, mp$. Because of the logarithmic singularity of initial function at $m2 = 0$, I expect real smooth answer depending on $\ln\left( \frac{Ss}{m2^{2}}\right)$. The full output for the integral (including many-many terms) also seems to have such structure: although there are many logs and polylogs, they're smooth in $m,mp \to 0$ limit.

However, Mathematica says: Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. And the output contains terms like $\infty - \infty$.

What is the technical reason for this incorrect output, and are there any ways to avoid it?

Comment: This might have something to do with the fact that you are telling *Mathematica* to find an antiderivative (by using the notation `Integrate[expr, x]` rather than `Integrate[expr, {x, a, b}]`), which doesn't have to be continuous. [See this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/). It explains the possible problem.

Comment: @march : thank you, I'll investigate this question. I'm using the construction Integrate[] and then take a difference just because this speed up the calculations in many times. If this is the reason for discontinuity, it's very sad...

Comment: (1) Your code assumes the hypotheses of the fundamental theorem of calculus are met and that the FTC can be applied. I cannot tell at a glance whether that is true. Are you sure it is? (2) `Limit[CrossSection[Ss, m, m2, 0], m -> 0]` returns `Indeterminate`. Not sure what to infer from that.